# Show properties dialog box after user creation

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a powershell script that creates a new user in Active directory, based on the contents of a CSV file. 
The new user is 95% complete upon creation, but needs to have additional AD groups added manually. 
These groups are too complex to add with a script, as it is based on case by case basis with a lot of exceptions / additions.

Therefore I would like to know it if is possible to show the newly created users properties window after creation? Like simulating right-clicking the user and selecting "properties".

Comment: *"These groups are too complex to add with a script, as it is based on case by case basis with a lot of exceptions / additions."* - I would try to sit down and write the steps you take (in your head) in a formal manner and turn that into a script.

Comment: Not going to happen. We have several hundred (if not thousands) groups and polices, any of which a user can be a member of. That is a lot of permutations, which is simply not feasible to script out, unless I want a massive, bloated script. It would take longer time to make the script, than it would to add those groups manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible since `dsa.msc` is not scriptable.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer. Explains why my google-fu couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers not done, but doable COM objects are provided for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry  but I think it's something that can be found. Have a look at [Extending the User Interface for Directory Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676902(v=vs.85).aspx). More exactly [Active Directory Users and Computers Property Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms674989(v=vs.85).aspx). You can read :

*"The Active Directory Users and Computers MMC snap-in is designed to display a property sheet for various objects in an Active Directory server. The property sheet contains one or more pages that are used to view and modify object data. Different object types have different sets of pages displayed for them."*
...

*"Some applications, other than the Active Directory Users and Computers MMC snap-in, must provide the user with the ability view and edit attributes for an object in an Active Directory server. The application could implement its own property sheets, but it is better to offer a consistent user interface to reduce confusion and learning time."*

**Fortunately, the Active Directory Users and Computers MMC snap-in allows any OLE COM application to display a property sheet for an object that is identical to the property sheet that would be displayed by the Active Directory Users and Computers MMC snap-in for the same object.**

In my experience I already use via PowerShell the Directory object Picker. Perhaps somebody do the same for Hosting an Active Directory Users and Computers Property Sheet in a Window Dorm callable from PowelShell.